# SSHTunnelForwarder works fine in command line python but raised import error in Apache WSGI application

Tags: python, apache, openssl, anaconda, mod-wsgi

I am using SSHTunnelForwarder to connect remote database, I run the following code in command lind python client within `Anaconda` environment and it works fine.

```
    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('ip', 22),
        ssh_password="pass",
        ssh_username="name",
        remote_bind_address=('localhost', 3306)) as server:
    #connect DB
```

The problem was when I deployed the same piece of code in an WSGI application in apache2 with mod_wsgi, I got the error:

```
ImportError: /home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so: undefined symbol: X509_get_signature_nid
```

I thought it was because Apache has exported `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which is not `/home/user/anaconda2/lib/`. Then I modified file `/opt/lampp/bin/envvars` adding one line `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/anaconda2/lib` at the end. I then restarted Apache but still got the same error.

Are there any other env variable that I ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use Anaconda Python inside of an Apache which has mod_ssl being loaded. This is because Anaconda Python has its own separate SSL libraries, but Apache will load the system ones. Once that happens, Anaconda code using SSL will break.

Comment: i see, no way to walk around?

Comment: Don't load mod_ssl if you aren't using it. Or use mod_wsgi-express instead to run separate instance and setup front facing Apache (which is using mod_ssl) to proxy to it. Or don't use Anaconda Python, use the system Python instead, which should use same SSL libraries as what Apache uses.